# What's the best alternative to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges (MVC3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've already checked the other questions and searched in google, but I found a lot of solutions...

What is the best?

I need to Alter the table when the DataModel changes, and I need an automatic Solution (like the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges does..

Thanks a lot for all replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for CodeFirst Migrations. [CodeFirst Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx). You Need EF 5 binaries.

Run the `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations` command in Package Manager Console

`Add-Migration` will scaffold the next migration based on changes you have made to your model.
`Update-Database` will apply any pending changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

To update the Entity Framework EDMX and sync it with your DB changes you double click on the EDMX in the VS2010 Solution Explorer. This brings up the designer (Model Browser window apparently is what it’s called) with a class layout of your entities. Right click anywhere on the designer surface and you’ll see an option in the dialog to “Update Model from Database.” Click on this and you get brought into the Update Wizard where you can choose the database objects you want to Add (if new), but by default it refreshes existing objects.

One thing the wizard doesn’t seem to do is delete columns from existing objects. Probably some sort of safety mechanism, but if you deleted the column from the database, do you really want to keep it in your entity? Ah well, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

It don't works well all the time. In my case I try to create nothing manually with the model editor so each time I modify my database model, I open the EDMX editor, I select all entities and I delete them then, I right click the model and I select option : Update from database.
When the object list appear, I select all table and next. It update the model.